# rsync-like tool that supports compression and maintains hardlinks?

Tags: backup, rsync, compression

I use an `rsync`-based backup scheme to maintain daily (and soon weekly and monthly as well) "snapshots" of my file server, using `rsync`'s link-dest feature to store hardlinks between the snapshots for files that haven't changed. This works very well: Backing up more than 330 GB of data, an entire snapshot takes up only 1.5 MB on disk if no files changed.

Recently a hard drive failure in this server shocked me into the realization of how fragile I am right now -- while I lost no data thanks to these backup snapshots, the backups and the data they back up both live in the same physical box in the office in my apartment; something as simple as a small fire in my apartment building could completely obliterate every last bit (pun intended) of my data!

I have an off-site location that I could be taking external hard drives to, so I intend to implement a rotating off-site backup wherein I would have one hard drive offline and off-site while a second is plugged in and backing up my snapshots, and I would periodically (e.g. once a week) swap them, so that if the worst does happen I lose at most the last weeks' worth of data.

Now here's the rub: I want to backup my snapshots, not the data itself, on the external hard drive. (I failed to notice the failed hard drive for a day, so that day's daily snapshot is all but worthless; having additional snapshots, however, is what saved my bacon, and I want that same level of assurance here as well. Note to self: Actually *monitor* that handy SMART data...) Tried-and-true `cp` won't work because it will see individual files, not hard links, increasing storage needed by 7 fold! `rsync` would work, but I'd like the data on these external drives to be compressed so that I can get away with having smaller drives (I'm targeting 1TB, more than enough for the current 337 GB of data but markedly smaller than the nearly 3TB capacity of my file server; I don't expect to be able to back up all 3 TB to just a 1 TB drive, even with compression, I just want the 1 TB to have a maximum useful lifespan as my data grows).

So, does anyone know of a method by which I could maintain hard-link associations between the snapshots while also compressing the files I'm backing up? The ideal solution would also support an exclusion list so I could simply skip compressing already-compressed files (.zip, .gz, .mp3, .jpg, etc.).

Just for absolute clarity, I'm looking for a scheme where a hard-link in /backup/snapshots/daily.1/file1 that points to /backup/snapshots/daily.0/file1 would get copied over to /mnt/external_hdd/snapshots/daily.1/file1 as a hard-link that points to /mnt/external_hdd/snapshots/daily.0/file1, the latter of which (the actual file itself) is now compressed (e.g. gzip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`rdup-simple`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdup-simple) (from [rdup](http://www.miek.nl/projects/rdup/)). You said you wanted compression, but in case you change your mind, I strongly recommend [**rsnapshot**](http://www.rsnapshot.org).

By the way, if two hardlinks point to a file, it's the same file. You can't compress only one of the hardlinks since it's the same underlying data in the file-system.

Comment: Right, I know that a hardlink to a compressed file is by definition simply another "access point" to that same compressed file, I was just trying to make it clear that I want the same hardlink structure in the backup of the snapshots. Thanks for the references, I'll look into these and see if they look like they'll indeed fill my needs.

Comment: Yes, `rdup` looks like the solution I was looking for. Too bad it sends entire files instead of only changes like `rsync` does, but then again it's typically relatively small files (code, text docs, etc.) that change, while the big ones that really benefit from that mechanism (photos, movies) rarely if ever change, so that shouldn't really be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could do compression at the filesystem level. However, none of the traditional filesystems on Linux support filesystems, which leaves you with three choices.

- [Btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), still considered experimental
- [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) (not in the mainline kernel, available as an [add-on](http://zfsonlinux.org/) or [through FUSE](http://zfs-fuse.net/))
- a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) stackable filesystem [providing compression](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=CompressedFileSystems), such as [FuseCompress](http://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/) or [CompFUSEd](http://www.biggerbytes.be/).

You'll get a much better compression ratio if you compress a big archive than if you compress many small files separately. So it would be a good idea to use archives on your external media. Just use any archive-using backup software, for example [duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/). You can still browse archives easily with Gnome or KDE virtual filesystems, or with any program through [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) (`mountavfs; ls ~/.avfs$PWD/archive.tgz#/path/to/archive/member`).